# Shell Script HereDoc : Stopping a process from reading "" from stdin after it has finished reading from HERE doc

Tags: shell, io-redirection, ksh

I have a program with the following logic, which continuously reads input and prints out the read input.

```
int main()
{
  while(1){
     std::string str;
     std::cin>>str;      // Read a string

     std::cout<<"\""<<str<<"\""<<std::endl<<std::flush;
     str.clear();

     sleep(1);
  }
}
```

Now i start this program from ksh, feeding few lines of input using a HERE doc.

```
abi@linux:~/Tst> ./a.out << EOF
> Hi
> How
> are
> You
> EOF
"Hi"
"How"
"are"
"You"
""
""
""
""
""
""
*i entered <ctrl+C> here to stop the program* 
abi@linux:~/Tst>
```

My Question is, I have provided only 4 lines as input from HERE doc,

But after the inputs are exhausted, the a.out continuously reads NULL as the input and prints out "".

why is this happening ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program as presented will *never* terminate; as you have a

```
while(1) {
    do_things_forever();
}
```

Because it never terminates, and stdin will be null once you reach the end of input, it's doing exactly what you ask it to.

You probably want something akin to:

```
std::string str;
while( !( std::cin >> str ).eof() ) {
   std::cout << '"' << str << '"' << std::endl << std::flush;
   str.clear();
   sleep(1);
```

}